# Magento 2: Override gallery.html file from vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/gallery

Tags: magento2, overrides

How to override file from vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/gallery folder.

I have to some changes inside gallery.html file and gallery.js file.
How to override those file inside my custom theme.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have to just create **mage** folder inside our theme.

```
Magneto2/app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/web/mage
```

Keep gallery folder inside mage and remove var folder and apply command

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Its working fine.